# 'dict' object is not callable for my Flask API

Tags: python, flask

I have written a Flask API. This is a very basic API which has two classes, namely User and Addresses. It creates a user with the data from the request when the respective endpoint is hit but I am getting an error saying `'dict' object is not callable`. Following is my code for the API:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    pass

    def __init__(self, name, username, password, addresses=[]):
        pass

    @property
    def to_json(self):
        pass
        return jsobj


class Address(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    pass

    def __init__(self, email):
        self.id = str(uuid.uuid4().hex)
        self.email = email


@app.route('/api/users', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
   pass

    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    resp = jsonify(user.to_json())
    resp.status_code = 201
    return 201
```

The error appears in the create_user method at line `resp = jsonify(user.to_json())`. any idea as to what might be wrong here? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set `to_json()` as `property` so you need just remove brackets

```
user.to_json()
```

replace to

```
user.to_json
```

Comment: yep, that was it. (Y)

Comment: btw I am getting another error on the same method saying `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: i'm not sure but may be you need `return resp`  instead of `return 201`

Comment: Oh yeah. I was returning `resp` initially, but commented the second-last and third-last lines to debug the error and changed response to `201`. And then forgot to change it back. Thanks